# Flutter video fails to play when the APK is built using M1 Mac

Tags: android, flutter, apple-m1

I am a bit puzzled as running the same codebase on the same devices gave different results. Flutter SDK is the same. The weird thing is the video is a simple assets in mp4 format, and the App builds and run and on my **Samsung S10** but the video is not playing only when I install the **APK** built using my M1 MacBook Air.

We are using an older version of `video_player` I looked at the changelog and did not find anything in particular.

[image]

### `flutter doctor` on M1 MacBook Air

[image]

### `flutter doctor` on Intel MacBook Pro

[image]

Any pointers will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That video player might only support `x86_64` but no `ARM64` architecture on OSX.

Comment: Sorry perhaps my wording wasn't clear, in both cases I was running it on an Android physical device, Samsung S10. I only built the APK from M1 Mac.